# How to get MvvmCross vNext to compile on Mac using MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to compile the vNext branch of MvvmCross on a Mac to try & start doing some iOS development using PCL's & MvvMCross.

I have spent a couple of days on this now but appear to be going in circles... being somewhat new to both C# & the Mac.

I have installed MonoDevelop 3.1.1 as recently referred to on @slodge's blog.
I have updated the targets file as per this reference  https://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets
I have downloaded the vNext branch from GitHub.

I have loaded the mvvmcross_all.sln in MonoDevelop however building it using the Debug|iPhone Simulator profile gives me 3 errors.

I have not been able to work out how to fix the references errors as for example appear in CrossUI.Core, ie references to

System
  System.Core
  System.Net

etc

Each of these lines has an error of Assembly not available for .NetPortable 4.0 Profile1 Profile (in Mono 2.10.9)

I realise its all a moving target but its obviously possible to get it to compile.

Any suggestions as to what I may have missed would be appreciated.

TIA,

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Andreas

In the version referenced in the blog at http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/a-patched-monodevelop-for-pcls.html, it appears that MonoDevelop reports that CrossUI is missing its references - but it still compiles. See this screenshot from my Mac - solution explorer reports problems but 'rebuild all' on CrossUI succeeds.

[image: screenshot]

If you get problems with building, please do report the build output and I'll try to help.

Note that the patched version of MonoDevelop also still has other problems - e.g. syntax highlighting and intellisense issues- [MonoTouch: creating multiplatform apps using Portable Class Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764011/monotouch-creating-multiplatform-apps-using-portable-class-libraries)

---

Alternatively, there are some iOS/Mac friendly binaries on SkyDrive - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/p/mvvmcross-binaries_7.html

---

The schedule for 'proper' support of Portable Class Libraries is aiming for a demonstrable version before Evolve (so less than 2 months away). Until then I'll personally continue to do most of my PCL work in VS, with the platform specific steps in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Hi Stuart, Thanks for the reply. For some reason when opening the project this morning a build all was successful. Andreas